# Mutex or Semaphore for two different threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp, async-await

I have two `async-await` that connects to the same TCP port.

`RSP` polls every `20000ms`.

`SP`polls every `500ms`.

Another method, `RP` , polls whenever it is called, so it can be random.

For now, whenever `RP` is called a few times, the whole system freezes.

I would like to know if **Semaphore** or **Mutex** will be more suitable in this case and how should I use it.

I've check the examples for **Semaphore** but it seems like most of them uses one method but tries to run 5 of them at the same time. How can I use them on two different methods?

```
static SemaphoreSlim _sem = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
public async void RSP()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            _sem.Wait();
            //DoWork
            _sem.Release();
            Thread.Sleep(20000);
        }
    }
    );
}

public async void SP(CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {                
            try
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return;
                }        
               _sem.Wait();
               //DoWork
               _sem.Release();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return;
                }
                break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you (silently) ignore `Exception` in your `catch` handler, bad things happen.

```
try
{
   //...
   _sem.Wait();
   //if an exception happens here
   //you won't know about it because
   //logic in the catch means it will
   //be ignored.
   //Even worse... the line below won't be called
   _sem.Release();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //...
    break; //oh s**t. how will we ever know?
}
```

It's a perfect recipe for a dead-lock.

How to improve?

```
try
{
   //...
   _sem.Wait();
   try
   {
       //do work
   }
   finally
   {
       _sem.Release(); //called, even if there's an exception
   }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //...
    //this is just sloppy. never ignore ALL exceptions
    //fix this.
    break; 
}
```

As an aside, it looks like you're doing a lot of synchronous blocking operations and mixing them with `async await`. This isn't how it's meant to be used. There are Task/async network methods that it looks like you are not using, you're using `Thread.Sleep` where you could be using `await Task.Delay`. `SemaphoreSlim` offers Task/async support for waiting for the semaphore with the `WaitAsync` method. There's probably nothing in your code that requires stopping the execution with a wait, sleep or sync IO. Learn async properly and stop tying up your ThreadPool with threads that are sitting around waiting or sleeping.